# Unable to git clone from self-hosted GitLab instance with custom port 6022

Tags: git, docker, gitlab, devops

I am trying to clone a Git repository from a self-hosted GitLab instance that is running on a custom port 6022, but I am unable to do so. Here's what I've tried so far:

- I have confirmed that the GitLab instance is up and running on port 6022 by checking it with terminal command lsof, netstat, etc.
- I have created an SSH key and added it to my GitLab account.
- I have tried to clone the repository using the SSH URL provided by
  GitLab, like this:

  ```
  git clone git@mygitlabinstance.com:6022/my-username/my-repo.git
  ```
- I have also tried to specify the custom port using the -p flag, like this:

  ```
  git clone -p 6022 git@mygitlabinstance.com:my-username/my-repo.git
  ```

However, both of these methods result in the following error:

```
Copy code
Cloning into 'my-repo'...
ssh: connect to host mygitlabinstance.com port 6022: Connection refused
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

how can I clone the repository from my self-hosted GitLab instance on port 6022?

this is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  web:
    image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ee:latest'
    restart: always
    hostname: 'gitlab.example.com'
    container_name: gitlab-ee
    environment:
      GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
        #external_url 'https://gitlab.example.com'
        #external_url 'http://localhost:80'
        gitlab_rails['smtp_enable'] = true
        gitlab_rails['smtp_address'] = "***"
        gitlab_rails['smtp_port'] = 587
        gitlab_rails['smtp_user_name'] = "developer@*.com"
        gitlab_rails['smtp_password'] = "**"
        gitlab_rails['smtp_domain'] = "**.com"
        gitlab_rails['smtp_authentication'] = "login"
        gitlab_rails['smtp_enable_starttls_auto'] = true
        gitlab_rails['smtp_tls'] = false
        gitlab_rails['smtp_openssl_verify_mode'] = 'peer'
        gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 6022
        nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = true
        nginx['ssl_certificate'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/fullchain.pem"
        nginx['ssl_certificate_key'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/privkey.pem"
        nginx['ssl_dhparam'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/dhparams.pem"
        # HTTPS Setup
        #letsencrypt['enable'] = false
        #external_url 'https://gitlab.example.com'
        #gitlab_rails['gitlab_https'] = true
        #gitlab_rails['gitlab_port'] = 443
    ports:
      - '8081:80'
      - '8443:443'
      - '6022:22'
      - '587:587'
    volumes:
      - '$GITLAB_HOME/config:/etc/gitlab'
      - '$GITLAB_HOME/logs:/var/log/gitlab'
      - '$GITLAB_HOME/data:/var/opt/gitlab'
      - '$GITLAB_HOME/config/ssl:/etc/gitlab/ssl'
        #networks:
```

Comment: You being able to _browse_ into the gitlab service points to https being the transport to be used instead of ssh. Are you able to connect to that service using an ssh client?

Comment: @eftshift0 i cant ssh to the server port 6022 but i can do it on port 22

Comment: ssh server uses different port than web server so if you can access 6022 through web browser then it means that it is not an ssh port. So you should ask server admin which port is in use by ssh.

Comment: my bad its not web browser but a terminal command. my ssh port in server is 65022 and for the docker gitlab i set it to 6022 and in container i set it to 22. '6022:22' @user7860670

Comment: just updated the question @user7860670 its lsof, netstat, etc.

For the container its `22` and for the server we set it to `6022`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem that I need to open the port on the cloud service settings in my case `Alibaba Cloud`. I need to add up `dest 6022/6022` on the port setup.

```
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
Welcome to GitLab, @x!
Connection to x.x.x.x:6022 closed.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you map the host port 6022 to the container port 22, that means you expect SSH inside the container to answer to port 22 (which is expected, as it is the default port).

However, your Omnibus GitLab instance running *inside* that container is instructed to set public SSH URL using port 6022, as documented in "**[Expose GitLab on different ports](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/docker.html#pre-configure-docker-container)**".

That means an URL like this should work, as described in [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/gitlab/comments/sbcghd/redirect_ssh_by_user_into_docker_container_with/):

```
git clone ssh://git@mygitlabinstance.com:6022/my-username/my-repo.git
```

Comment: tried the command and it didnt work @VonC

Comment: @Sam Can you edit the question with the output of `ssh -Tv git@mygitlabinstance.com:6022`?

Comment: Solved the problem now its the redirection of the subdomain to host machine IP problem @VonC

Comment: @Sam Wait... that is not how questions work. If you have found an answer, post it here (it will help others), you can accept your own answer by the way. Then ask a separate question (with a link back to this one for context).

Comment: okay, I will be doing that @VonC